# Why is NVCC more strict with constexpr than non-constexpr host functions?

Tags: compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc, compiler-bug

Consider the following code:

```
constexpr __host__   void foo() {  }

__global__ void baz()
{
    if constexpr(1==2) { foo(); }
}
```

this [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/14nxjvbnY) with CUDA 11.3.1's NVCC. However, if I remove the `constexpr` - it [does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/zxK6Ejr4s).

How come? Is this a bug?

Comment: it's a [stated limitation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constexpr-functions).  The reason things work when you remove the first of your two `constexpr` keywords, is because another aspect of C++ allows it to.  But since execution space decorators are not part of the C++ language, the compiler may enforce those rules as it sees fit, and in the order it sees fit.  If you think its a bug, feel free to [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But: my code doesn't break the limitation: It doesn't call foo from the `__device__` version of the function.  If it were considered to be calling it, then the second version should not have compiled either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I've filed it with NVIDIA:

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/3328502

(it's difficult to access their bug tracking system, try going through https://developer.nvidia.com first to login, then look at your bugs, then replace the bug number.)

A fix is apparently now in the works!